# Window Function - date ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, window-functions, sql-date-functions

I'm trying to calculate duration between different status. Which is working for most part.

I have this table
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efSeU.png)

for id = 102, I was able to calculate duration of each status.

```
with ab as (
          select id,
                 status,
                 max(updated_time) as end_time,
                 min(updated_time) as updated_time
          from Table
          group by id, status
)

select *,
        lead(updated_time) over (partition by id order by updated_time) - updated_time as duration,
        extract(epoch from duration) as duration_seconds
from ab
```

[Output for id = 102](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d86ix.png)

but for id = 101, status moved between 'IN_PROGRESS' to 'BLOCKED' & back to 'IN_PROGRESS'
here I need the below result so that I can get the correct IN_PROGRESS duration
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4xVQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to track every time there is a change of STATUS for a given ID sorted by VERSION. The below query provides the desired output. More than brevity, I thought having multiple steps showing the transformations would be helpful. The column UNIX timestamp can be easily converted to human readable DateTimestamp format based on the specific database being used. The sample table definition and file used has also been shared below.

Query

```
WITH VW_STATUS_CHANGE AS
(
SELECT ID, STATUS, LAG(STATUS) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY VERSION) LAG_STATUS, VERSION,  UNIXTIME, 
  CASE WHEN LAG (STATUS) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY VERSION) <> STATUS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END STATUS_CHANGE
  FROM STACKOVERFLOWSQL
),
VW_CREATE_SYNTHETIC_PARTITION AS 
(
SELECT ID, STATUS, LAG_STATUS, VERSION,  UNIXTIME,STATUS_CHANGE, 
        SUM(STATUS_CHANGE) OVER (ORDER BY ID, VERSION) AS ROWNUMBER

FROM VW_STATUS_CHANGE
) ,
VW_RESULTS_INTERMEDIATE AS
(
SELECT ID, STATUS, LAG_STATUS, VERSION,  UNIXTIME, STATUS_CHANGE, 
"FIRST_VALUE"(UNIXTIME) OVER (
            PARTITION BY "ID",
            "STATUS",  ROWNUMBER
            ORDER BY
                "VERSION" 
        ) "TIME_FIRST_VALUE",
        "FIRST_VALUE"(UNIXTIME) OVER (
            PARTITION BY "ID",
            "STATUS", ROWNUMBER
            ORDER BY
                "VERSION" DESC
        ) "TIME_LAST_VALUE" 
FROM VW_CREATE_SYNTHETIC_PARTITION
ORDER BY ID, VERSION
)
SELECT DISTINCT ID, STATUS, TIME_FIRST_VALUE, TIME_LAST_VALUE
FROM VW_RESULTS_INTERMEDIATE
ORDER BY TIME_FIRST_VALUE
```

AWS Athena Table Used along with Sample data.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE STACKOVERFLOWSQL (
   ID INTEGER,
   STATUS STRING,
   VERSION INTEGER,
   UNIXTIME INTEGER
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HIVE.SERDE2.OPENCSVSERDE'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'SEPARATORCHAR' = ',',
   "SKIP.HEADER.LINE.COUNT"="1"
   )
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'S3://<S3BUCKETNAME>/';
```

Dataset Used:

```
ID,STATUS,VERSION,UNIXTIME
101,NOT_ASSIGNED,1,1668124141
101,IN_PROGRESS,2,1668124143
101,IN_PROGRESS,3,1668124146
101,IN_PROGRESS,4,1668124150
101,IN_PROGRESS,5,1668124155
101,BLOCKED,6,1668124161
101,BLOCKED,7,1668124168
101,IN_PROGRESS,8,1668124176
101,IN_PROGRESS,9,1668124185
101,IN_PROGRESS,10,1668124195
101,COMPLETED,11,1668124206
105,NOT_ASSIGNED,1,1668124207
105,IN_PROGRESS,2,1668124209
105,IN_PROGRESS,3,1668124212
105,IN_PROGRESS,4,1668124216
105,IN_PROGRESS,5,1668124221
105,IN_PROGRESS,6,1668124227
105,COMPLETED,7,1668124234
```

Result from the View

```
ID  STATUS  TIME_FIRST_VALUE    TIME_LAST_VALUE
101 NOT_ASSIGNED    1668124141  1668124141
101 IN_PROGRESS 1668124143  1668124155
101 BLOCKED 1668124161  1668124168
101 IN_PROGRESS 1668124176  1668124195
101 COMPLETED   1668124206  1668124206
105 NOT_ASSIGNED    1668124207  1668124207
105 IN_PROGRESS 1668124209  1668124227
105 COMPLETED   1668124234  1668124234
```